# Midpoint Euler method for second order system, cant get it to work

Tags: matlab, debugging

I need to plot this simple system:

x'' = -x

using midpoint Euler.

u1 = -x , u2 = -x'

u1' = u2
u2' = -x

u1(n+1) = u1(n) + h*?
u2(n+1) = u2(n) + h*f((1/2)*(u1(n) + u1(n+1))

We dont know u1(n+1). I tried approximating it with u1(n+1) = u1(n) + h*u2(n)

u2(1+i) = u2(i) + h * ((-1/2) * (u1(n) + u1(n+1))

Then we have u2(i+1) and u2(i). A midpoint value is (u2(1+i) - u(i))/2

u1(q+i) = u1(i) + h*midpoint

When i plot this the result is some awful diverging line, not an oscillating function. What is wrong?

```
clear all, close all, clc

h = 0.0005; % steplength
nos = 500000; % number of steps

x = zeros(1,nos);
xp = zeros(1,nos);
energy=zeros(1,nos);

% Starting positions
x(1) = 1;
xp(1) = 0;

for i=1:nos-1    



    xpp = -x(i);

    xTAYLOR = x(i) + h*xp(i);

    xp(1+i) = x(i) + (-1*((1/2)*(x(i) + xTAYLOR)));

    xpHALF = (xp(1+i) - x(i))/2;

    x(1+i) = x(i) + h*xpHALF;


end

plot(x)
```

Comment: When I run your minimal example, I get [this figure](http://oi39.tinypic.com/35hqsm1.jpg) - is that your *awful diverging line* ?

Comment: Why are you using the mid-point euler method when a simple euler will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I'm whacked, but I'm seeing a slight issue with how the problem is posed.

```
u1 = -x , u2 = -x'

u1' = u2
u2' = -x
```

Let me try this:

```
u1 = -x
u2 = -x'

u1' = -x' = u2
u2' = -x'' = x = -u1
```

When I do that I get some sweet sweet oscilations!  Here's my attempt, just using `ode45`, but you should have similar luck with the sign change.

```
[t2,y2] = ode45(@(t,x) [x(2) -x(1)]',[0 250],[0 1]);
```

[image: Oscillations]

HTH!!